# swprintf locale

Tags: c++, string, locale

using c++ on windows,

trying to set the locale to be used by the swprintf function.

i need to include the thousand separator with the number which is printed out.

i tried several options...

```
_wsetlocale(LC_NUMERIC, L""); //default locale
```

also..

```
_wsetlocale(LC_NUMERIC, L"english");
```

and of course..

```
swprintf(buf, L"%d", 3546);
```

i also tried to display the number as follows

```
auto locale = _get_current_locale();
_swprintf_l(buf, L"%d", locale, 3546);
```

i need to get the thousands separator, i.e 3,456

i also placed a breakpoint to see the value of the `locale` variable, it contains the `lconv` struct with the thousands separator correctly set to `,` ... however, swprintf is ignoring it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tested on Linux**

Try with that :

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "en_US.ISO8859-1");
```

Example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
        setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "en_US.iso88591");
        printf("%'d (%s)\n", 12345, setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, NULL));
        return 0;
}
```

You are missing the `'` use `%'d` and not `%d`

Still working with wchar

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void)
{
        setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "en_US.iso88591");
        wprintf(L"%'d\n", 12345);
        return 0;
}
```

An other example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void)
{
        wchar_t buf[32];
        setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "en_US.iso88591");
        swprintf(buf, 32, L"%'d", 12345);
        wprintf(L"%ls\n", buf);
        return 0;
}
```

**Windows**

Well today I did test on Windows (with mingw) and this is not implemented...
Please read this link, which provides a solution http://c-faq.com/stdio/commaprint.html

Comment: same result, the locale has the "," thousand separator when i break and watch `locale` but swprintf ignores it :(

Comment: i'm using wide stings, `if (swprintf(buf, L"%'d", 12345) > 0)` is printing out the literal `'d` and not the number

Comment: thanks for your updates. i'm using c++ on Win32. your example `"%'d"` is printing out the literal `'d` and no number

Comment: Updated for Windows... Sorry I was running my test under a Linux box

Comment: Thanks for the windows workaround. I implemented it using std::string, as it looks safer.